# Select unallocated hardware

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this data:

[image]

[image]

How to select the hardware that are not allocated yet?

There are two cases:

1. The hardwares that does not exist in `employee_hardware`
2. The hardwares that exists in `employee_hardware` but there is no 
   `allocated = TRUE` row

This is my try but it is not correct because it shows multiple rows of the same hardware.

```
SELECT h.hardware_id
    ,h.hardware_name
    ,h.created_at
    ,h.updated_at
FROM hardware h
LEFT JOIN employee_hardware eh ON h.hardware_id = eh.hardware_id
WHERE h.hardware_type_id = 2
    AND (
        eh.employee_id IS NULL
        OR eh.allocated = FALSE
        )
ORDER BY h.hardware_id
```

[image]

Comment: what is the database you are using ?

Comment: I'm sorry I missed it. Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT h.*
FROM hardware h
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 'a'
                    FROM employee_hardware eh 
                    WHERE h.hardware_id = eh.hardware_id
                    AND eh.allocated = TRUE
                  )
```